# Difference between idx_tup_read and idx_tup_fetch on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, index-statistics

On Postgres 8.4 when you do:

```
select * from pg_stat_all_indexes where relname = 'table_name';
```

It returns the fields idx_tup_read and idx_tup_fetch, what is the difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When looking at the source code of the view, then you'll see that `idx_tup_read` is the result of calling `pg_stat_get_tuples_returned()` and `idx_tup_fetch` is the result of calling `pg_stat_get_tuples_fetched()`

[The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html) describes the two functions as follows:

> pg_stat_get_tuples_returned(oid)
>
> Number of rows read by sequential scans when argument is a table, or number of index entries returned when argument is an index
>
> pg_stat_get_tuples_fetched(oid)
>
> Number of table rows fetched by bitmap scans when argument is a table, or table rows fetched by simple index scans using the index when argument is an index

Answer (score 5):

From [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW),

```
idx_tup_read is number of index entries returned by scans on this index
idx_tup_fetch is number of live table rows fetched by simple index scans using this index
```

so, the `read`s are when index gives back position of the row required and `fetch`es are when the index gives back the table rows themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation [page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW) says that the difference between them appears:

1. when the index is involved in a bitmap index scan
2. if any dead or not-yet-committed rows are fetched using the index
3. if any heap fetches are avoided by means of an index-only scan
4. when the index is accessed by the optimizer's checks

In all these cases `idx_tup_read` becomes greater than `idx_tup_fetch`.